# soap messages are not visible in tcp/ip monitor

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I just implemented a web service client for consuming the webservice. The web service wsdl is located in http://www.webservicex.net/StockQuote.asmx?WSDL, To consume the web service I used wsimport after that I created client logic like the following:

```
package com.ram.ws.client;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;

import net.webservicex.StockQuoteSoap;

public class StockClientCall {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.webservicex.net/StockQuote.asmx?WSDL");
        QName qName = new QName("http://www.webserviceX.NET/", "StockQuote");
        Service service = Service.create(url, qName);
        StockQuoteSoap soap = service.getPort(StockQuoteSoap.class);
        String result = soap.getQuote("FB");
        System.out.println("Result is "+result);
    }

}
```

and for tracing I configured the settings in TCP/IP monitor like the following:

[image]

am I configured in mis-manner because I'm getting an empty console in TCP/IP please correct me if I'm wrong ..

Comment: Why trace it? Just use SOAP UI and you will see the request and response. SOAP UI is ideal for testing.

Comment: Hey Namphibian ...Than for comment..I just familiar with TCP/IP & I dont know completly about SOAP UI ..Thats why I simply follows TCP/IP..

Comment: Just download SOAP UI create a new project point it at the WSDL URL and all will be made clear. SOAP UI is a test framework for SOAP and REST services and once you use it there is no alternative.